# Commutation of ladder operators in reciprocal space

Tags: condensed-matter, operators, commutator

For simplicity, let's assume a hamiltonian of the form

\begin{equation}
H=\sum_{\vec{r}}\sum_{\vec{\delta}}a^+_{\vec{r}}a^-_{\vec{r}+\vec{\delta}}
\end{equation}

where the $\vec{r}$ 's are the sites in a lattice, the $\vec{\delta}$ 's  are the vectors pointing from $\vec{r}$ to a neighbor and $a^{\pm}_{\vec{r}}$ are the creation and annihilation operators in a site $\vec{r}$. Because $a^{+}_{\vec{r}}$ and $a^{+}_{\vec{r}+\vec{\delta}}$ are evaluated at diferent sites, they commute so H can be changed to:

\begin{equation}
H=\sum_{\vec{r}}\sum_{\vec{\delta}}a^-_{\vec{r}+\vec{\delta}}a^+_{\vec{r}}
\end{equation}

So far so good. Now I Fourier transform to diagonalize H with this transformation:

\begin{equation}
a^{\pm}_{\vec{r}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{\vec{k}}e^{\pm i \vec{r} . \vec{k}}a^{\pm}_{\vec{k}}
\end{equation}

Where N is the number of sites and $a^{\pm}_{\vec{r}}$ are ladder operators in reciprocal space. Now H is:

\begin{equation}
H=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{\vec{r}}\sum_{\vec{\delta}}\sum_{\vec{k}_1, \vec{k}_2} e^{i\vec{r} . (\vec{k}_1 - \vec{k}_2)}e^{-i\vec{\delta} . \vec{k}_2} a^+_{\vec{k}_1}a^-_{\vec{k}_2}
\end{equation}

If we sum over $\vec{r}$ we get a Dirac delta and this collapses to

\begin{equation}
H=\sum_{\vec{\delta}}\sum_{\vec{k}} e^{-i\vec{\delta} . \vec{k}} a^+_{\vec{k}}a^-_{\vec{k}}
\end{equation}

Now, $a^+_{\vec{k}}$ and $a^-_{\vec{k}}$ doesn't commute so now **order matters**. However, if I had changed the order before, as I did in the second equation, I would have obtained a diferent H:

\begin{equation}
H=\sum_{\vec{\delta}}\sum_{\vec{k}} e^{-i\vec{\delta} . \vec{k}} a^-_{\vec{k}}a^+_{\vec{k}}
\end{equation}

which one is correct? Am I missing something here? It seems like the operators in direct space can be exchanged but once I transform to reciprocal space and collapse the sums it can't be done anymore, so I'm getting two different results.

Comment: Yet, the ladder operators a_k1 and a_k2 do commute so before summing over r you can just switch them, avoiding the problem

Comment: You assume summation over + and - *δ* s, no? This is so H is hemritean before diagonalization. After diagonalization, again, hermiticity collects the exponentials into cosines. Repeating for your alternate equivalent starting point, you obtain the *same* hermitean answer in the sum.

Comment: Diagonalize the hermitean $a^\dagger b+ b^\dagger a= b  a^\dagger + a b^\dagger$ for just two sites to reassure yourself you get a unique answer, before generalizing your lattice.